# Best way to query a list of dates that are between two dates in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm looking for a way to query a list of dates that are in range of two dates.
I have a Command model, and I'm trying to find all the commands that have startDates in between a given range of time.

What I tried so far is:

```
const commands = await Command.find({
    _id: device.zone,
    startDate: {
      $gte: NEXT_SEVENTEEN_HUNDRED.toDate(),
      $lte: NEXT_NEXT_SEVENTEEN_HUNDRED.toDate()
    }
  }).sort({ startDate: 1 })
```

And this does not work.

My apologies if this is a simple question, I'm new to mongoose and having trouble navigating through their docs.

Comment: What *does* the code snippet do? Does is error out? Provide invalid results?

Comment: I noticed that you are also filtering results with `_id`. What does this do? I thought only one document could have a specific `_id`. Also, are you storing your dates as numbers, like from doing `Date.now()`, or a different format?

Comment: @robinsax hey, it did error out by sending a 500, but turns out it was something unrelated to this, and it turns out the query actually worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator:

```js
const commands = await Command.find({
  $and: [
    { _id: device.zone },
    { startDate: { $gte: NEXT_SEVENTEEN_HUNDRED.toDate() } },
    { startDate: { $lte: NEXT_NEXT_SEVENTEEN_HUNDRED.toDate() }}
  ]
}).sort({ startDate: 1 })
```

Comment: This worked!, thank you. Is there a term for the $and operator u used so i can look more into this, I'm having trouble figuring out what the different terms mean on mongoose.

Comment: You want to look at the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/). Mongoose is an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) for MongoDB., so many of the documentation you need you will find it in the MongoDB reference page. Please remember to upvote the comment if it helped you.